# No values, no axis name in a plotcp

Tags: plot, axis

I use the `rpart` package and when I use `plotcp`, the plot does not display the axes' names neither the values on the axes.

[image: Plotcp]

How do I fix that ?

EDIT : here is the code

```
library(rpart.plot)
library(rpart)
train<-read.table(file="synth_train.txt",header = TRUE)
tree <- rpart(y~., data=train, method="class", minsplit=2, cp=0 )
plotcp(tree)
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: I managed to make the axis names and values be displayed but then again I change the codes and the plot were displayed without names and values

Comment: I used dev.off() and it worked. Problem solved

Comment: Post an answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used dev.off() and it worked